# Which format to use for image with floating point values?

Tags: image, matlab, floating-point

For technical purpose I need to work with matrices gray level (images) containing floating point value that can exceed 1. (Example: `2.3324`)

Which format should I use to store them in a file? I would like to avoid to bring them back to the range `0...1` when Matlab write them to disk.

I know I could just dump the matrix with `save('myfile','myImage','-ascii')` but I would like to use a graphical format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FITS file format would be an option (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FITS).

It has support in many languages, including MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
save('myFile','myImage')
```

That insures that you will not lose any data in conversion, and the underlying *.mat files are pretty efficient.